# How to link java application against 3rd party libs within deployment environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, deployment, devops

Let's say I have a **web-app.war** containing Spring Boot application with libraries (**.jar** files) inside `WEB-INF/lib`. Then Someone has removed some of the libs from **web-app.war**. I put this archive on the deployment server and I have all the dependencies on that server (e.g. somewhere in `/3rdparty/*.jar`). I need to run my app with command `java -jar web-app.war`. I've read about classpath and I tried to do the following: `java -cp /3rdparty/*.jar -jar web-app.war` However I got the error: `Could not find or load main class`. I cannot rebuild my app within deployment server, I cannot avoid the situation that I described above, so is it possible to achieve my goal?

P.S. Probably this is a kind of dummy question but I really did not find anything non-trivial regarding this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try use [loader.path](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.html#executable-jar-property-launcher-features) to add external jar. Also here some [example](https://medium.com/@Jeef/dynamically-loading-libraries-into-a-springboot-application-at-run-time-80639ee5aab)